Which component failure can lead to a green screen, followed by no display after reboot?
I was playing a video game, when suddenly my monitor displayed green bands. I wasn't able to do anything, so I hard shut down the PC.
After reboot, nothing is displayed on the monitor. And I mean nothing, no logo, no stuff to access the BIOS, nothing. The power button is on, and a fan is turning, but that's all. No beep or anything weird from a sound point of view.
My PC is quite old (I got it in 2014), so I don't find this surprising that some component broke after all this time, but I wonder which component should I replace to fix this.
I don't have much (not at all, to tell the truth) knowledge in that domain, so probably that my hypotheses don't make much sense, but my process of thought was:

If nothing is displayed, maybe it comes from the GPU?
But if that was the case, shouldn't I at least be able to access the BIOS?
If it was the motherboard, would the PC even boot at all?

It's not a laptop, so I can easily — or so I think, I want to take this opportunity to learn — change a component. Tell me if you need additional details.

If the GPU is poked (and the green lines could definitely imply this, making it my first guess), there is no way to output video - even for the BIOS.  Any video output requres a GPU - albeit often a very basic one built into the CPU will suffice.  If your PC has both an onboard and discrete video output, try removing the discrete one and seeing if you get an output on the onboard output.

@davidgo Thanks for your help!

Following the comments, I've removed my GPU and tried to instead use the video output directly provided by my motherboard, and the computer booted without problem.
So, the problem came from the GPU indeed!
